# How to prove/see ActiveMQ Artemis RemoteConnectionFactory is using compress-large-messages="true"?

Tags: compression, jms, activemq-artemis

Here's the attribute setting

```
<connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" compress-large-messages="true" \>
```

Comment: Is that your actual configuration? Then it would be invalid, you need to use  `/>`, not `\>` to close an element. If you try to use an invalid configuration it won't accept these settings.

Comment: What/where is the setting on ActiveMQ 5.5.0, please ? (assuming it's an xml property)

Comment: trying jms.useCompression=true in the connection string.

Comment: ... and adding that to the url worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Large" messages which are compressed get a special boolean property named `_AMQ_LARGE_COMPRESSED` set to `true`.